# Running Pig Word Count Script on Amazon EMR Getting Error

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-pig, amazon-emr

the following is a sample of my code. I am trying to make a demo of a wordcount of the old testament. When I attempt to run this code through amazons EMR the step fails. I have uploaded the code to EMR as a plain text file and all my paths are correct.

Here is my code:

```
a = load 's3://joe-hadoop-first-try/oldtest/oldtest.txt' as (f1:chararray);
b = foreach a generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(f1)) as word;
c = group b by word;
d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT(b), group;
store d into 's3://joe-hadoop-first-try/wordcountoutput';
```

Here is the error output:

```
3904 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer  - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. <file s3://joe-hadoop-first-try/input/wordcountoldtest.txt, line 2, column 52>  mismatched input '$0' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
```

The beginning of the sample text looks like this:
The text file is the old testament in plain text format. Here is a sample of the beginning: The Project Gutenberg EBook of The King James Bible This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with almost no restrictions whatsoever. You may copy it, give it away or re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included with this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.org Title: The King James Bible Release Date: March 2, 2011 [EBook #10] [This King James Bible was orginally posted by Project Gutenberg in late 1989]

Additionally, this error still occurs when a text file only containing:

```
helloworld
```

Is used as the input

Here is the attempted solution using a schema:

```
a = load 's3://joe-hadoop-first-try/oldtest/oldtest.txt' as (f1:chararray);
b = foreach a generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(f1)) as word;
c = group b by word;
d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT(b), group;
store d into 's3://joe-hadoop-first-try/wordcountoutput';
```

This code is working now! Corrected all errors

Comment: What does the content of the text file look like?

Comment: I have added the information to my main question

Comment: Please edit your question to add that, not the comments.

Comment: Are there newlines in that anywhere?

Comment: Yes, but the error still occurs when I use a text file with only:

helloworld

no linebreaks and no spaces.

Comment: Your error says you are missing a right parentheses on the second line, but it looks fine to me. Can you try loading the file with a schema? `load 'path' as (f1:chararray)` then use `f1` instead of `$0`

Comment: This has produced same error, please see original post for my code

Comment: No, don't copy exactly what I typed... When you do `a = load 's3://...'` give it a schema there. Also how do you expect the data in `a` to be loaded? By default, the text will be split on tabs.

Comment: My mistake, had to read about schemas, this is my first time using this language. This was a sample tutorial but I can't get it working. Trying your suggested solution again now. Please see the original post for my corrected code.

Comment: No worries. Now, you don't need to cast `f1`,  so you can remove `(chararray)`

Comment: Testing now, please see main post in a minute or two. Edit: No this did not work as posted in original either. I will have error logs in a few minutes.

Comment: You haven't answered the earlier question. Do you want to load the data by newlines or tabs? I would also recommend capitalizing the pig functions like FLATTEN,  FOREACH, and GENERATE

Comment: hello all errors have been fixed, my output was part-r-10000 and SUCCESS

Comment: So the solution was capitalizing the functions (at least FLATTEN)?

Comment: The solution was changing the output file to a non-previously-defined location.

Comment: Ah. You should've posted that error message instead, then. Oh well. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: No don't worry, your solution was the first error message, then when it went to store the data it encountered another error. You're corrections were necessary.

Comment: Alright, well if my suggestions truly helped, you can show your appreciation by clicking the checkmark next to my answer below.

Comment: Of course, just began using this site, sorry for not accepting earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking from the comments to fix the problem.

1. You can load the data using a schema instead of casting inline.
2. Some of the Pig functions only work correctly when capitalized.
3. Make sure your inputs and outputs are pointed to the correct places

So, the full code should look like this

```
a = LOAD 's3://joe-hadoop-first-try/oldtest/oldtest.txt' AS (f1:chararray);
b = FOREACH a GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(f1)) AS word;
c = GROUP b BY word;
d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT(b), group;
STORE d INTO 's3://joe-hadoop-first-try/wordcountoutput';
```

Also, by default, the LOAD operation will split the data by tabs. If this is not the correct behavior, the delimiter can be changed using PigStorage like so for newlines

```
a = LOAD 's3://joe-hadoop-first-try/oldtest/oldtest.txt' USING PigStorage('\n') AS (f1:chararray);
```